# Problems with uploading from ios to server

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make an upload function for images in a IOS app. But when I use the code below - then nothing is happend! It works with text, but not the image.

My image is taken with the camera, and then placed in a UIImageView.

My question is; how I get the image from the imageView into the uploade script?

```
- (IBAction)sendAnmeldelse:(id)sender {

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bild.png"];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://gourmetkongen.dk/data/upload.php";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];


    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSLog(@"Sending succes!");
}
```

And here is the image in the UIImageView:

```
UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
imageView.image = image;
```

Hope someone can help me!

//
And here is the PHP-code:

```
$uploaddir = '';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: can you share php script or which ever technology you are using at web end ?

Comment: dont you need to send the request over some kind of connection object ?

Comment: The PHP-code is above!

Comment: YvesLeBorg I don't understand your question:(